# Filter an intent by package in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Is it possible to filter an intent by package? That is to say, I only want to filter Google Maps action.SEND intents to process them in my app. For example, in Google Maps, I want to share my location with the option "Send location to others". I want, only in this chooser, to appear my app.

I've done this, but I know I miss something.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <!-- Something here with com.google.android.apps.maps? -->
        </intent-filter>
```

Thanks!

Comment: In onReceive() (onCreate(), onStart() depending on how you process the message)  you can say intent.getPackage() to retrieve the sender package. Hopefully it will work!

Comment: Actually the comment above seems incorrect. Documentation says:
"Retrieve the application package name this Intent is limited to. When resolving an Intent, if non-null this limits the resolution to only components in the given application package."

So that means the package of the receiver (us), and not the sender!